# List removed package apt-get

Tags: apt-get

I accidentally run `sudo apt-get remove --purge openssl` on Ubuntu 18 Mate and it started deleting important packages. How can I reinstall all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that apt asks you if you really want to do what it is showing you, so you could have prevented this in first place by answering with **N**o.
Rolling back after a package installation/removal is not trivial.

To "unroll", you'll have to manually consider `/var/log/apt/history.log` and re-install the removed packages. In the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133328&s=4027d0898ffb2401d389ae0509d6b248&p=12593297#post12593297), you can find a command that automatically lists all removed packages. But be careful with that and future package installs/removals. Although it might look like a trivial action to install/remove a package, it is not.